# Evaluating limit in multivariable calculus problem

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(2x+y)\sin(x+y)}{(x+y)\sin(2x+y)}$$

Comment: @Kevin What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried multiplying by the conjugate of x-y but I am very stuck

Comment: $\lim_{t\to 0}(\sin t) / t = 1$ is all you need

Comment: oh boy wow thank you totally forgot about that!

Comment: You can edit your answer to include what you tried, instead of mentioning it in a comment. In general, questions (and answers) are seen as primary on Stack Exchange sites, whereas comments are regarded as secondary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x+y=z$ and $2x+y=w$, then $z$ and $w$ tend to zero as $x$ and $y$ tend to zero and use the above-mentioned limit $\lim_{t\to 0}(\sin t) / t = 1$.